# How to use input from user through MDDialog in kivymd and kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am making a simpel todo app which takes input from user through MDDialog and add to MDDataTable tempraly i want to know how to use user input in MDDialog to insert in MDDataTable ‫‫‫‫‫‫‫‫‫‫‫‫‫‫‫‫‫‫‫‫‫‫‫‫‫‫‫‫‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫ ‫

```
from kivy.core import window
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDToolbar
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton, MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog



window.Window.clearcolor = (0, 0, 0, 1)
window.Window.size = (360, 600)


KV = '''
<Content>
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "12dp"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "120dp"

    MDTextField:
        hint_text: "Enter a Todo"

    MDTextField:
        hint_text: "Enter Time"


MDFloatLayout:

'''


class Content(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Example(MDApp):
    
    dialog = None
    def build(self):
        
        tool_bar = MDToolbar(
            title= "Todo",
            pos_hint ={'center_y':.95}
        )
        
        
    
        data_tables = MDDataTable(
            size_hint=(1,.9),
            check = True,
            column_data=[
                ("", dp(10)),
                ("Content", dp(35)),
                ("Time", dp(15)),
            ]
        )

        add_button = MDIconButton(
            md_bg_color = self.theme_cls.primary_color,
            icon = 'plus',
            pos_hint = {'center_x':.5},
            on_press = self.show_confirmation_dialog
        )
        
        
        screen = Screen()
        screen.add_widget(tool_bar)
        screen.add_widget(data_tables)
        screen.add_widget(add_button)
        screen.add_widget(Builder.load_string(KV))
        return screen


    def show_confirmation_dialog(self, obj):

        def close_dilog(obj):
            self.dialog.dismiss()
        
        def use_input(obj):
            print('heare i wan to print the Todo and time')

        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                title="Address:",
                type="custom",
                content_cls=Content(),
                buttons=[
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text="CANCEL",
                        theme_text_color="Custom",
                        text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,
                        on_press = close_dilog
                    ),
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text="OK",
                        theme_text_color="Custom",
                        text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,
                        on_press = use_input
                    ),
                ],
            )
        self.dialog.open()


Example().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A convenient tool to help access data from the GUI is to use `ids`. Here is a modified version of your `kv` that adds `ids` to your `Content` class:

```
<Content>
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "12dp"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "120dp"

    MDTextField:
        id: todo
        hint_text: "Enter a Todo"

    MDTextField:
        id: time
        hint_text: "Enter Time"

MDFloatLayout:
```

Then you can use those `ids` in your `use_input()` method:

```
    def use_input(obj):
        print('heare i wan to print the Todo and time')
        print('todo:', self.dialog.content_cls.ids.todo.text)
        print('time:', self.dialog.content_cls.ids.time.text)
```